# Two subgroups are conjugate

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ a un group and $n\geq 2$ be an integer. Let $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ be two subgroups of $G$ that satisfy

$[G:H_{1}]=[G:H_{2}]=n \hspace{0.4cm} $ and $\hspace{0.4cm} [G:(H_{1}\cap H_{2})]=n(n-1).$

Prove that $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ are conjugate in $G$.

I don't know how can i start, because i know that $G/H_{1}$ and $G/H_{2}$ have the same number of elements and for $n=2$ $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and maybe i have that.But for $n>2$?How can i find some element in $G$ to show the conjugation? Can you give me some hint to prove this proposition? Thank you.

Comment: There's an answer, and hints, and a long discussion there, so you can choose what you want.

Comment: This is Problem 7 from the IMC 2020 https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?year=2020&section=problems&item=prob7q

Comment: yes, that is the question.Thank you